# How to add style module to

Tags: qml

I want to implement the 'Style singleton' pattern.
My project files are contained in a folder and this has one subfolder named Style
This subfolder contains 2 files :
Style.qml -

```
import QtQuick 2.0

QtObject {
    property color systemControlColor: "#B7B865"
}
```

and qmldir -

```
module Style
singleton Style 1.0 Style.qml
```

Then I attempt to import -

```
import Style 1.0
```

But this gives me an error

```
module "Style" is not installed
```

What am I missing ?

Thanks

Comment: show your ,qrc.......

Comment: Qt version, some code, folders/qrc structure ... come on, give us as much information as you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use pragma Singleton in your code

```
pragma Singleton
import QtQuick 2.0

QtObject {
    property color systemControlColor: "#B7B865"
}
```